# What is the medical term for semi-mindless activities to help reduce anxiety? ... such as gardening, mowing, cleaning... perhaps driving

Tags: cognitive-psychology, behaviorism, stress, anxiety

What is the medical term for semi-mindless activities to help reduce anxiety? ... such as gardening, mowing, cleaning... perhaps driving.

I recall that, maybe, the word asynchronous was part of the term *** which based on present answers now seems less likely *** .

Comment: I am not aware of a medical term but what's wrong with the non-medical term *hobbies* or *interests* ?

Comment: @ChrisRogers perhaps it's because those don't really mean a way to reduce anxiety? I think the correct word is *distractions*

Comment: [Displacement activity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_activity)?

Comment: Displacement activity would seem to be involuntary.

Comment: @Randy The purpose of the semi-mindless activities, to begin with. Are they meant to decrease anxiety, or to increase well-being? The behavioral terms are different, based on the expected outcome of a specific behavior.

Comment: I do not understand Erik... the question states "to help reduce anxiety" ... what is not clear.

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning [mindful meditation](https://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/consumer-health/in-depth/mindfulness-exercises/art-20046356).  While the activities exampled are not specifically anxiety-reducing, they may have an anxiety-reducing component, which can be thought of as meditative.  Mindful meditation practices can incorporate such activities, so long as one is mindful of their attention, focus, and thoughts during the activity.

Comment: @DevSolar  not what I was looking for but a very useful answer regardless… Never heard of that but it’s good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have read it mentioned as **grounding-** techniques or activities. Activities that pull you into the present, and, if possible, fulfill you by giving you the impression towards achieving a goal.

Answer (score 4):

I have not been able to find any term, medical or non-medical, which includes the word *asynchronous*, but to add to the answer by @user20460 there is the non-medical term *hobbies*.

Taking part in hobbies and other interests is recommended to anyone who suffers from anxiety and/or depression because not only can it provide a distraction, but it can also alleviate boredom which in itself [can create or exacerbate anxiety](https://www.anxaid.com/hobbies.html) - see also, [Csikszentmihalyi (2000)](http://www.doctorhalima.az/files/books/positive_thinking_books/beyond_boredom_and_anxiety_csikszentmihalyi_en_1518.pdf).

As NoPanic.org [points out](https://www.nopanic.org.uk/keeping-stress-to-a-minimum), you should...

> do something that makes you happy. Every day should include a bit of ‘ME’ time. It may be losing yourself in a book, playing or listening to music or a self-pamper session. However busy life seems, you deserve that special time.

### References

Csikszentmihalyi, M. (2000). *Beyond boredom and anxiety* (Vol. 721). San Francisco: Jossey-Bass.

Comment: Then I'm probably wrong about asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing sounds a lot like aspects of Occupational Therapy (sometimes called Ergotherapy). Occupational therapy can include prescribed activity such as knitting (to meaningfully occupy your time) and is applied to a wide range of health related issues including anxiety.

Here is a dictionary definition of Occupational Therapy 
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/occupational%20therapy

And here is a link to a definition from the University of British Columbia https://osot.ubc.ca/about/what-is-os-ot/

Comment: OT is not exclusively the prescription of activities like knitting and gardening, but this is just one aspect. Here is a recent scientific article describing these practices from the journal "Occupational Therapy International"   https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22489029

For some less scientific articles about the use of such activities in OT https://psychcentral.com/blog/arts-crafts-in-psychiatric-occupational-therapy/
https://www.newgradoccupationaltherapy.com/early-occupational-therapy-history

Comment: Those kinds of tasks are part of Occupational Therapy. I'm looking for the term used to describe the kind of tasks that are useful ... 'semi-mindless' or Grounding Techniques as noted above, which is a perfectly good answer for me and I've marked it as such.